# Acer leaves turning brown

Tags: diagnosis, maple

I recently bought a Japanese jewel green acer and live in the north east of Scotland. Having planted it a week ago it now has brown leaves developing, mainly on the top of the plant. I have attached pictures of the change.

It’s is potted in a shaded area under a big tree so I don’t think it has been damaged in direct sunlight. The temperatures have been between 15 and 20 Celsius for the past week. Having checked the pot this morning the soil has moisture in it but I don’t think it is overly wet either. I mixed existing compost with some perlite for the soil mix. I fed it a few days ago using a liquid seaweed feed. There has been little to no wind and it is a nice sheltered area.

Does anyone know what is causing this? Would it be happier with more sun?
[image]

[image]

Comment: When you bought it, was  it  under shelter at the garden centre, not completely exposed outdoors? Also, when was it last watered and  how much water did you give it (I'm assuming there are drainage holes in its pot)?